# application of open() and fopen()

Tags: c, file-descriptor

There are differences between `open()` and `fopen()` function. One is system call and other is library function. I try to figure out what is the application of these two function but I found nothing useful. **Can you give some scenarios where to use `open()` and where `fopen()` should be used?**

Comment: The `open` function is only a system call on some POSIX systems. On e.g. Windows it's a normal library function just like `fopen`.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you need a file descriptor.  `open()` gives you one.  Sometimes you need a `FILE*`, in which case use `fopen()`.  You can always turn your `FILE*` into a file descriptor via `fileno()`, whereas the opposite transformation is not really supported.  It mostly depends on what downstream functions you intend to call with the file handle.

Comment: Which are the cases where open() is more proper than fopen().

Comment: When you only want to call functions that require a file descriptor, and no functions that require a FILE*.

Answer (score 0):

`open()` will return the file descriptor. We overwrite the file, while using the `fopen()` we cannot overwrite the file. We use the file descriptor for reading and writing using the other
functions like `read()`, `write()`, etc. But in `fopen()` it will return file descriptor we have to use `fprintf()` to write to the file stream. `sscanf()` to read from the stream.

Comment: We can use other functions like lseek to write at the middle of the file too.